# Pass special character through query string in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

When I try to pass some special characters, though query string in the URL property of the Ajax post method, it seems to be some error happened. That means I won't get correct special characters when hitting controller action in ASP.NET MVC 4.

My code is

```
var temp=temp@#$#%#%#979

url=(Controller/Action/id/name?departname=+temp);
```

Comment: are you making a ajax post from javascript? or a form?

Comment: [Unsafe Characters in URLs](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke..i had to pass special charoctor as query string in a real case scenario.

Comment: @BenG.. yes from a ajax post method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` for encoding the parameter

```
var temp = temp@#$#%#%#979
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(temp)
url = (Controller/Action/id/name?departname=+temp);
```

and  use Server.UrlDecode for decoding the parameter in controller

```
var Depart = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["DepartmentName"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

> request from a script function from a cshtml formajax

If you are making your ajax request from javascript, then use `encodeURIComponent`:-

```
var temp = encodeURIComponent('temp@#$#%#%#979'); //temp%40%23%24%23%25%23%25%23979
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ASP.net, however most languages require you to URL encode strings that are meant to be used as part of a URL.

For example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I hope this helps get you moving in the right direction.